# Google Play Store Overflow Menu

Tags: android, android-spinner, popupwindow, android-popupwindow

I am really confused with what is this view.

[image]

The one that I am referring to is the `pop window`? or the `spinner`? that is showing whenever we click the overflow icon in the items in Google Play Store.

Anyone who knows what is that view being used?

Is that a `popup window`? or a `spinner`? or other?

And also please provide some documentation about it if possible.

Thank you very much in advance. I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Yeah, it is a [PopupMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html)

Comment: context menu https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#context-menu

Comment: Thanks ianhanniballake and kris larson.
One thing, if its a PopupMenu, why isn't it showing line dividers? All I see when I search PopupMenu is always having a line divider.